# How can I remove references to tables after removing .frm files?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

So I had a bunch of csv files in my `/var/lib/mysql/imports` directory for importing into mysql tables I had created.  To clean up the folder I deleted all the files in the directory (incorrectly thinking it only contained .csv files).  The only problem was that the folder also stored table data from my imports database.  Now that I realized my error I was just going to recreate the database I did delete and re-import from the csv file.  However I cannot create the table again because mysql must have references to the table.  How can I remove this table completely so that I can simply recreate it and re-import the information?

Edit:

```
mysql> DROP TABLE imports.ncaa_passing_statistics;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'ncaa_passing_statistics'
mysql> SELECT * FROM imports.ncaa_passing_statistics;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'imports.ncaa_passing_statistics' doesn't exist
mysql> CREATE TABLE imports.ncaa_passing_statistics (id INT);
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`imports`.`ncaa_passing_statistics`' already exists
mysql>
```

Comment: Can you tell if those were MyISAM or InnoDB tables? I suppose InnoDB, so they have been deleted from the filesystem but not from InnoDB's internal dictionary.

Comment: They are InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

Shut down mysql.  What files do you see?  Restart mysql; are things better now?

One *possible* fix is to CREATE a new table (with a different name), copy the .frm to somewhere else, drop the table, shutdown, copy the .frm back as the problematical table name, restart.

Comment: So I shutdown by doing... `service mysql stop` and `service mysql start` ... not sure if that's correct. I checked for file changes inbetween those and after and none of the `.frm` files i removed showed up again... or anything other than the csv files currently in the folder.

Comment: I added some mysql information to my original post perhaps that'll clear things up a little?

Comment: It is the fix, it is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

Comment: Tried that and named it the same thing as the table in question and doesn't seem to work for me. It simply says... `ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'ncaa_passing_statistics'
`

Comment: @daveomcd could you paste literally every single command (sql and OS) that you did before getting that?

Comment: @jynus, sorry I don't remember what they were.  What eventually worked for me is (1) Created a new schema named 'info_imports', move any csv files to import into that folder. (2) I then recreated the few tables and reimported.  (3) I dropped the old schema 'imports' which finally was allowed, and recreated 'imports' and copied over the tables.